# current_user association seems to work in view but not controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, devise

The rundown: I have a user model which `belongs_to` a state model (region). The state model rb file is basically empty except for: `has_many` users. The db is seeded with the state info, and when a user registers they can select their region; all works fine.

Now I'm trying to use devise's `current_user` method in one of my controllers to check if the `current_user`'s `state_id` is a match to one of those in the array.

```
class FinancesController < ApplicationController
def index
  @user = current_user
  if @user.state_id == ['53', '54', '60']
    flash.now[:notice] = "User is from one of the accepted regions"
  else

  end
end
end
```

Schema: (the dots are just there to indicate that there's more than just the two lines)

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    .........
    t.string   "email",                               null: false
    .....
    .....
    t.integer  "state_id"
    .....
  end
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, and will always use the "else" even if the user is of one of the accepted values in the array.

For example, the user I'm testing with has a state_id of 54. In my view I can use `<%= current_user.state_id %>` which will print "54" on the page.

I believe the problem may be with the array `['53', '54', '60']` because I tried just having one ID there instead of the array,  and it seemed to produce the proper results. Perhaps I should be using a for loop to cycle through and check each number in the array if such is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking a string value against an array.

You would probably want to do this instead:

```
if [53, 54, 60].include? @user.state_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to remove the ' ' quotes from around the numbers also it seems, but now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [include](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) method:

```
['53', '54', '60'].include?(@user.state_id)
```